# List View Item Details - Accordion vs Sticky Modal/Popover

Tags: accordion, listview, master-details, popover

I need to show a large block of details (and actions) for an item in a list. I'm comparing 1) An accordion vs 2) Bottom sticked modal/popover. The list remains usable in both options.

[image: Opening item details block - Accordion vs Sticky Popover]

**ACCORDION**

PROS:

- Details block is "grouped" with the selected item.
- Classic (expected) to users.

CONS:

- Less convenient to review a sequence of items (needed sometimes).
- A bit less good visual design (+ details block width must be similar to row width).

**STICKY POPOVER**

PROS:

- List is not interrupted (needed sometimes)
- A bit better visual design (+ details block width is adjustable to the content).

CONS:

- Partial (visual) disconnection between the selected item and its details.

[image: Accordion vs Sticky Popover]

What would you choose?